# SSDT update schema when data exists

Tags: sql-server, database-migration, sql-server-data-tools, data-migration, database-project

I have an SQL server DB project with some table structure, for example:

tblUser 
Id
Name
CustomerTypeId

This is the production database and it contains a lot of data.
Next, I need to add a new table

tblCustomer
Id
Name

and remove the CustomerTypeId column from the tblUser table and move data from tblUser to tblCustomer with the CustomerTypeId = 3.

The first issue is happening when I try to update the scheme - Possible data loss because I remove the CustomerTypeId column and the next issue is how I can migrate the data from one table to another and how can I track if migration is currently applied and I don't need to apply it again.

Answer (score 1):

You have an option in the Publish Profile configuration to disable failure on "Possible data loss".
[image]

For the second part then there are few possibilities, but all of them would have the same logic --> write a script in a way it won't be executed several times or make the script to be idempotent, so you'll be able to re-execute it as many times as needed:

- In your post script check if the insert/update was made already and run insert if only needed, for example:

```sql
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE SOME_COLUMN = 3)
BEGIN
  -- your logic here
END
```

- Another possible way would be to put the data manipulation script to the separate file and check if it was ran or not every time.